# How to remove xmlns tag from xml element using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to remove this xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0" from all xml element except root tag.  xml element using C#. I have written below code to get to as xml form. But unable to remove xmlns tag from xml element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QualityDeviationCaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <CaseID xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0">2</CaseID>
 <Description xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0">Air filter is not present</Description>
 <StartDate xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0">0001-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
 <LastUpdated xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0">0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastUpdated>
</QualityDeviationCaseType>
```

After remove xmlns="http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0" this tag, my result should return like this as below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QualityDeviationCaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <CaseID>2</CaseID>
 <Description>Air filter is not present</Description>
 <StartDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
 <LastUpdated>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastUpdated>
</QualityDeviationCaseType>
```

My C# Code, I am getting xml result from my XSD file.

```
connection.Open();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
adapter.Fill(dt);
myTestTable = dt.Clone();
DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select();

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
QualityDeviationCaseType oQualityDeviationCaseType = new QualityDeviationCaseType();

foreach (DataRow row in orderRows)
{
    oQualityDeviationCaseType = new QualityDeviationCaseType();
    oQualityDeviationCaseType.CaseID = row[0].ToString();
    oQualityDeviationCaseType.Description = row[3].ToString();
}

using (StringWriter stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QualityDeviationCaseType));
    ser.Serialize(stringwriter, oQualityDeviationCaseType);
    sampleChannel.Publish(stringwriter.ToString());

    //This line of code sending my xml file to IBM WMQ.
}
```

As per my above code, My result is coming with xml tag for each lement. I want to remove from element tag using c#.

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlns` attribute has important semantics in XML: it puts all elements in the default namespace `http://www.AB.com/BC/QualityDeviationCase/1_0`.

I am not familiar with C# specifically, however: removing it implies reasoning at the semantic level rather than syntactic.

Concretely, it should be done by removing the namespace of all elements in the XML document being exported, or not putting them in any namespace in the first place. If the C# library is complete, it should provide a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Regex?

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 ...
    string pattern = @"xmlns=""[a-zA-Z0-9:\/._]{1,}""";
    using (StringWriter stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QualityDeviationCaseType));
        ser.Serialize(stringwriter, oQualityDeviationCaseType);
        string s = stringwriter.ToString();
        Match m = Regex.Match(s,pattern);
        if(m.Success)
           s=s.Replace(m.Value, "");


        sampleChannel.Publish(s);
        //This line of code sending my xml file to IBM WMQ.
    }
```

I'm not that familiar with XmlSerializer, but that should work I think. Match will only find anything beginning with 'xmlns="' and ending with '"'.